# If a block header is 80bytes, then why does a full node need ~100GB of storage

Tags: blockchain, mining, blocks

So, I'm a little confused about how data is stored in a block. If You can get the state of all accounts from the State Root of a block header, then that means that you can get the state of every account from every block by collecting every block header ever mined. If a block header is 80bytes and there are ~10 million blocks on Ethereum, then you only need 0.8 GB to store every block header.

If this is so, then why does a full node download so much data?

Comment: Why would your question imply that a full node only stores block headers?

Comment: @pwagner that's what I assume would be in one considering you can derive the whole state of the blockchain from them